# How to write a file in the same package?

Tags: java, file

I have this code:

```
try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH)) {
            properties.setProperty("test", "test");
            properties.store(outputStream, null);
        }
```

with `PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH = "fileName.properties"`
This creates a file in the root of the project. The only way I found to avoid this, is to put the absolute path of the file, meaning:

```
src/main/java/com/comany/fileName.properties
```

But people told me that this wont't work outside the IDE, in "real life"... Because there is not such a thing as `src/main...` in a jar file.
What's the solution then??

Comment: you can write the file under the same folder with the jar

Comment: `But people told me that this wont't work outside the IDE, in real life` Did you try it out yourself to see what happened ?

Comment: Technically, you may be able to write a temp file and then save it into the jar using the built in `ZipFile` utilities. But I would really recommend against it. Although it might be a fun excercise. But don't deploy something like that.

Comment: You will have to store the data somewhere if you want it to save after the application stops running.

Comment: What you've shown is not an absolute path.  Absolute paths start with `/` or `\\`.  Anyhow, where do you want the file to appear in the jar?

Answer (score 0):

You dont normally modify files stored internally. Instead you should store an default file within the JAR and store any modifications as an external file.

You can use `Class.getResourceAsStream()` to access non-code resources within the JAR file.

Comment: This method returns an input stream, whereas the OP wants to write to the file, not read from it.

Comment: Yeah, but trying to suggest an alternative as writing to an internal file is not the most ideal

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,and use the set method `setParameters()` to write it

```
public class Configuration {
private Properties parameters;
private static Configuration instance = null;

private Configuration() {
    parameters = new Properties();
    try {
        parameters.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("fileName.proooooperties"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Configuration getInstance() {
    return instance == null ? new Configuration() : instance;
}


public static void writeProperties(String fileName) {  
    try{  
        FileOutputStream oFile = new FileOutputStream("fileName.properties", true);
        parameters.setProperty("test", "testing");
        parameters.store(oFile, "comments");
        oFile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
} 

public String getParameter(String name) {
    return parameters.getProperty(name);
}
public void setParameters(String name, String value) {
    parameters.setProperty(name, value);
}
```

}

Comment: The `getResourceAsStream` returns an input stream.  The OP wants to write to the file, not read from it.

Comment: i get it, source is updated. thank you for your remind

Comment: As far as I know, `parameters.setProperty` only sets the property in the properties object. It does not save the properties object to a file using `parameters.store`, which is what the OP wanted to do.  `parameters.store` requires an outputStream, whereas `getResourceAsStream` returns an inputStream.

Comment: `writeProperties（）` is added,

Comment: That is what the original poster already had. However, this was causing the file to be written in his root directory. Based on some searching around I did, I don't think what he wants is possible in general.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a configuration file, where I put the path of my properties file, which I put outside of the project.